# I am having trouble when it comes to if statments and importing other functions into the if statment

Tags: python, function

What I have written looks like this

```
def forward():

    user_input = input('\nWould you like to go backward?  ')

    if user_input in ('Backward' 'backward'):
        import backward

forward()
```

and then the second file backward is typed like this

```
def backward():

    user_input = input('\nWould you like to go forward?  ')

    if user_input in ('Forward' 'forward'):
        import forward

backward()
```

When the user inputs "forward" it will import into the backward file then going forward will work again but if they try and go backward the program shuts down and I can't figure this problem out.

I have almost completed a text based adventure but I can't find anything on how to resolve this problem.

Comment: What tutorial are you reading that has you doing conditional imports?

Comment: What do you want to do? What do you think importing a Python file does? What does actually happen when you run your code? (You say it 'shuts down', but I guess there is some error message.)

Comment: Is this all in a single file? Do you get errors when you try the import?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **Python modules aren't imported multiple times**!

Since imports are cached, and only run once, running an import two times or more will not execute or reload the module again.

If you want to reload a module, you have to use the [reload function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) inside `importlib` (Python 3.4) or `imp` (Python 3.0 to 3.3):

```
importlib.reload(module)
```

Note that as the documentation states the argument passed to `reload()` must be a module object, so it must have been successfully imported before. So in your case it would look like

```
import importlib
import backward
...  
importlib.reload(backward)
...
```

Comment: Okay I did this and it works to a point, but then the program decides to repeat asking if you want to go backward. It will ask forward, backward, forward, backward, forward, forward, backward, backward then forward once more and end the program. I also do not have a lot of experience with python and programming in general.

Comment: I would suggest that you restructure the application to gather navigation information and appropriate the correct response.

There could be a couple of reasons why your program is crashing. But without the code listing to test, it's hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are trying to do is :

- Ask the user for input
- If the input is 'Forward' or 'forward', then import the Forward module
- If the input is 'Backward' or 'backward', then import the Backward module

If this is true then I guess the following should work.

```
import importlib
import forward
import backward


def forward():
    importlib.reload(forward)

def backward():
    importlib.reload(backward)

def main():
    user_input = input('\nWould you like to go forward or backward?  ')
    if user_input in ('Forward' 'forward'):
        forward()
    else:
        if user_input in ('Backward' 'backward'):
            backward() 
        else:
            print 'The input was not recognised'
            main()
```

That being said, I don't understand what do you need to import the modules multiple times if you have imported them from the start.

Comment: Kind of. This is a test but basically I made about 20 different files and so if I go North South East or West it will import a different file so say you go East and then want to go back West then it should allow you to but occasionally it ends the program. Also if import is called at the beginning then it will import the other files and mess up the functions.